# How can I run several projects on the same solution in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-services

I have several projects in my solution (libraries, web apps, services,...) and I want to be able to run a service at the same time with my principal project.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click the solution and go into the properties to set the startup projects.

Here is the link to the official documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx